# What happened to the chat shortcuts in the side bar?

Tags: support, chat, meta

Evidence [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iJd2ki-WC6w). It's just a video.

It seems like the chat rooms have left me. I can't join chat rooms now via the side bar. I can only search for chat rooms with `chat.meta.stackexchange.com` now.  Usually the rooms should show at the sidebar!

I hate that. Why is this happening!?

See these photos taken from Mathematics SE. 
[image]
[image]

YA KNOW WUT I MEAN? HUH?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can you post some explanation in text?

Comment: There's a chat link on each and every page on all the sites. In the footer.

Answer (score 6):

The video is pretty useless in explaining what you are talking about - all I can see is you going through the front page of Meta Stack Exchange. No idea what that's supposed to mean in regards to "where are the chat rooms".

On any site, click the "Stack Exchange" dropdown - there is a link to the chat rooms for that site:

> [image: chat link in drop down]

You can also just go to https://chat.stackexchange.com directly.

Comment: Of course I know there's a chat button, but there should be some shortcuts to chat rooms at the sidebar (you know, where there's Hot Network Questions and stuffs).

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 so your actual question is not "How do I get to chat" (which is how your question reads), but "What happened to the chat short cuts in the sidebar".  I know you tried to address this in your edit, but you should make that point more clear.

Comment: Yeah.  Sorry :P I'm changing it now